# Email is sending to Gmail accounts but not on Yahoo accounts on web server using PHPMailer

Tags: email, smtp, localhost, phpmailer, yahoo

I am using PHPMailer class to send emails to other accounts. It is sending to only Gmail account but not on Yahoo account. But on localhost it is working fine. It was working fine one day ago, after I have made some changes, now its not sending email to Yahoo account.

Note: Above problem is in Web Server, Localhost is fine.

Below is my code.

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 
                'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true));

        // $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                           
        $mail->IsMail();
        $mail->Host = 'bmstestn@server2.navicosoft.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'bmstestn@server2.navicosoft.com';
        $mail->Password = 'Haroon.Iqbal3';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('bmstestn@server2.navicosoft.com', 'Masterect');
        $mail->addAddress('account@yahoo.com', 'Name');
        $mail->isHTML(true);      

        $message = "Hi";                           // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = 'Masterect Order Confirmation';
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } 
        else {
                echo "sent";
        }







[Fri Jan 19 15:58:23.912833 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 23055:tid 140635915826944] [client 170.130.37.42:47835] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini, referer: http://www.bmstest.net/
[Fri Jan 19 09:33:20.429221 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 112688:tid 140635966183168] [client 158.69.116.60:52558] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini
[Fri Jan 19 09:33:17.126644 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 112688:tid 140635991361280] [client 158.69.116.60:52472] AH01265: attempt to invoke directory as script: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/cgi-bin/
[Fri Jan 19 09:33:16.124489 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 112688:tid 140636083681024] [client 158.69.116.60:52453] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini
[Fri Jan 19 09:33:15.106902 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 112689:tid 140636050110208] [client 158.69.116.60:52420] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini
[Fri Jan 19 09:33:07.864161 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 112688:tid 140636058502912] [client 158.69.116.60:52207] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini
[Fri Jan 19 09:33:05.598524 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 112689:tid 140636504160000] [client 158.69.116.60:52128] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini
[Fri Jan 19 02:05:41.426570 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 73975:tid 140635949397760] [client 100.43.81.126:55018] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home2/bmstestn/public_html/php.ini
```

Comment: `$mail->Host = 'bmstestn@server2.navicosoft.com';`? That's an email address, not a host name. Doesn't matter anyway because you're sending through localhost using `mail()`. You need to check the mail server logs on your server.

Comment: I have checked by changing hostname. But still it is working same. Sending to gmail account but not on Yahoo. Even I have commented $mail->Host